# How to decode eval(stripslashes(gzinflate 

Tags: php, wordpress, decode, decoding

I've decoded code in footer and header of template, but don't know how to do it in functions.php in wordpress template.

Can you please decode this code:

```
<?php print(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("VZBNS8QwEIbvC/0PcyikhbJ611rY9QPZxZOKSKCUyYSETZOSpB4U/7uztCLCHGbeZ767m+sO9Owx2+ABDeGpNzQoilX9VWwAoHStFE+7l9cd7t/swd0e3h+OUlwtULfKRj+MVPX9/ePxru/rrRQXS4vtZKa/TNXqMJGvSt1IEaWoV4CtjpzOumq0dZTsJ3FQr1yjC+ksqFWwuko5TiFVJTalq9v2cl0VgNAEkOLZ2ATZ0EjATiRHQyIFs+elAHlath8EGMYx+ATOInmkBgbnOPCnBNafy0GHkLkimTA7xX3GgYH1ecD8exeAsrS438WG7f8PmRSbjp/8Aw==")))); ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking for a 'decode' of `eval` in your title? `eval` is not a decoder / string-manipulator, it _runs_ the code in the string it gets.

Comment: hey, your included code is already worked!

Comment: If the developer had this in his code, he obviously wanted you to leave the footer intact for credit. Don't remove the author's credit, it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

Change `eval()` with `echo`

```
echo stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("VZBNS8QwEIbvC/0PcyikhbJ611rY9QPZxZOKSKCUyYSETZOSpB4U/7uztCLCHGbeZ767m+sO9Owx2+ABDeGpNzQoilX9VWwAoHStFE+7l9cd7t/swd0e3h+OUlwtULfKRj+MVPX9/ePxru/rrRQXS4vtZKa/TNXqMJGvSt1IEaWoV4CtjpzOumq0dZTsJ3FQr1yjC+ksqFWwuko5TiFVJTalq9v2cl0VgNAEkOLZ2ATZ0EjATiRHQyIFs+elAHlath8EGMYx+ATOInmkBgbnOPCnBNafy0GHkLkimTA7xX3GgYH1ecD8exeAsrS438WG7f8PmRSbjp/8Aw==")));
```