# What does this encoded string say, and how did you find out?

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a catalog of products and I don't know what it is doing, and I'd like to peek inside. Can someone figure out how to print the source code and tell me how?

```
<?php ob_start();?>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<? $a=ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($a))); ob_end_flush();  ?>
```

Comment: Ehm. Just reposting is not appreciated here. Especially when there are already [dozens of questions like that](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eval%20gzinflate%20base64_decode).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode eval(stripslashes(gzinflate ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304911/how-to-decode-evalstripslashesgzinflate)

Comment: Sir, a link does not tell me that the code is encoded multiple times.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that is explained somewhere. But just two minutes of not reading through the search results obviously won't tell you that. (Also I'm not going to mention the automated services and scripts for that.)

Comment: I've already tried the automated scripts. I wouldn't be here if i could get them to work

Comment: Ha. No need to fib about it. You didn't bother to search.

Comment: Here is the decoded version after multiple encryption rounds: http://pastebin.com/k5amhaxA

Comment: wow thanks, how many rounds was it

Answer (score 4):

Change the `eval` call at the end of that junk to say `echo` instead. it'll spit out the decoded code.

```
[...snip....]; ob_end_clean(); echo(gzinflate(base64_decode($a))); ob_end_flush();  ?>
                               ^^^^---here
```

Comment: i did that but all I got when i ran it through a browser was ?>

Comment: view the page source to see the raw output, instead of the rendered output.

Comment: @user1093111: that's because it's encoded multiple times. You have to repeat it multiple times until you get the "true" source-code.

Comment: Ah ok. So I have to keep decoding the output?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($a)))`, do `echo gzinflate(base64_decode($a))` and repeat with the result until you get useful source code.

Comment: Yes, it's encoded multiple times. Therefore, keep repeating it. This may easily waste the better part of your day though. ;)

Comment: haha thanks a ton, I already have "wasted" the best part of my day;) but i'm learning so its all okay. Thanks again